# Validate Line function in Netsuite ?&Schedule Script function in netsuite?

Tags: netsuite

1.Validate Line Function
    Does this script fire at field level of Line Items OR fire at the record level?

2.Scheduled Script
    How to test Performance of a Script? Would debug help or are there any other logs to check on bottlenecks (delays)?

Answer (score 1):

1. *Validate Line* fires at the line level, i.e. not until you click "Done" or moving to the next line. Your event handler function can return `false` to stop the line addition/update from happening, or `true` to continue normally.
2. As far as I know, currently the debugger can only be used on User Event scripts. You could do some simple time measurements and log timings throughout your script. Your most likely points of bottlenecks will be anything that goes back to the database (e.g. creating/loading/submitting records, complex searches, etc).